# C# Buffer-error for multipart webrequest

Tags: c#, stream, buffer, filestream, multipartform-data

I am writing a program for batch-upload of images to celumimagine and get a error for some files when trying to upload them. The uploader class is run in a new task to help from locking the gui for the user. The error is as follows:

Error message:

```
The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

TargetSite: "{System.IAsyncResult InternalWrite(Boolean, Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)}    System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}"

Stacktrace: "   at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n   at System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteTo(Stream stream)\r\n   at CelumUploader.Uploader.UploadImage(FileInformation imageInformation, Folders folders, ObjectCollections objectCollections, Int32 retrys) in c:\\Users\\isMle\\Documents\\Projects\\Solutions\\TestSolution\\Test\\Test\\Classes\\Uploader.cs:line 136" string
```

I think the problem is somewhere in this code:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
     postDataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
postDataWriter.Flush();
fileStream.Close();
postDataWriter.Write("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
postDataWriter.Flush();

// Set the http request body content length
webrequest.ContentLength = postDataStream.Length;

log.Debug("Uploading file.");

// Dump the post data from the memory stream to the request stream
using (Stream stream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
{
      postDataStream.WriteTo(stream);
}
postDataStream.Close();
```

What am I doing wrong?